# Is there some way and is there a real need to improve the load time of our forum

Tags: performance, load

*Nice to meet you, colleagues*!

According to Alexa.com the average Load time for [our forum](http://www.seo-forum-seo-luntan.com) is "***Very Slow (3.741 Seconds), 89% of sites are faster.***"

The question is: Is there some easier way and is there a **real need** to improve the load time of our forum?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to improve the load time of your **forum** you should **start from your database**:

DB:

1) Optimize your queries. Run the [Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html) for a couple of days. Find the slowest queries and try to optimize them or re-write them in a different approach so they use [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html).

2) Use memory caching techniques like [memcache](http://memcached.org/)

3) Upgrade your DB server

WEB:

1) Minimize calls to your server. If you have a lot of images (avatars etc) try using an image server

As of the "real need", YES, faster is better. In case of a forum, page refreshes must be instant as users navigate through posts. Slow forum=Very bad user experience

Comment: @MisterL i took a look in your site and i saw you are using SMF. Since SMF is popular, its also worth checking for optimization specifically for the SMF script. Something like this:  http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/websiteperformance/smf.htm

Comment: Yes, it's SMF. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes people dont like to wait and will leave if it is too slow. Though 3 seconds is not much of a wait so you are probably good but some tips are:

- Combine css files (and minify them) where you can
- Use minified JS files, remove js files that arent needed.
- Dont overload forum pages with unneeded graphics ads etc
- make sure the forum software uses thumbnail versions of images in
  posts instead of full resolution